# Why are the react-router component props not including history?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I'm loving v4 but in 4.1.2 this keeps tripping me up when using the browser router:

With a component in a Route component I have these props passed in: `{computedMatch, location, path}` although the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) tells me to expect `{match, location, history}` which is what I get with the hash router.

To get the history passed in I have to use the `withRouter` wrapper which feels very clunky because the relevant component is the component prop to a Route component.

The documentation sounds right to me. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to `{match, location, history}` if you use Route as

```
<Route path="/" component={myComponent}
```

In above code you will have match location and history accessible inside myComponent.

Or else you have to use withRouter